# open chrome://inspect from shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

In order to troubleshoot development of a responsive website, I want to use chrome debugging. I have managed to jump through enough hoops to get my phone connected, but each time I want to begin, I have to type "chrome://inspect" into my browser bar. I dragged the favicon to my desktop and it made a link, but when I double clicked it, it complained about the protocol not having a handler. (I understand what a protcol is, in this case "chrome:" vs "http:" or "mailto:")

So, I made an HTML file and tried re-directing it to that URL. It seemed to do nothing. I created a bat file

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "chrome://inspect" --new-window
```

It opens chrome, but does not open the desired page.

It seems that Chrome has this locked down for security.

Is there a quick way to access this page?
Is there a quick way of accessing any / all "chrome:" protocol page(s)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open chrome and launch the settings page](http://superuser.com/questions/558672/open-chrome-and-launch-the-settings-page)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I think your Dupe suggestion is probably correct. I'll try the solution there when I have time later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:
1. Download AutoHotkey zip file from 'https://autohotkey.com/download/'.
2. Unzip and save it to a folder called 'autohotkey'.
3. Create the following batch file:

```
rem ----------------------open chrome://inspect----------------------
> "chromedev.ahk" echo winactivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
>> "chromedev.ahk" echo winwaitactive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
>> "chromedev.ahk" echo send ^^t
>> "chromedev.ahk" echo sleep 100
>> "chromedev.ahk" echo sendraw chrome://inspect/
>> "chromedev.ahk" echo sleep 100
>> "chromedev.ahk" echo send {enter}

call "%CD%\autohotkey\AutoHotkeyU32.exe" "%CD%\chromedev.ahk"

del "%CD%\chromedev.ahk"
```