# How do I open Chrome settings page using command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome

I need to open more than 100 different Chrome profiles on the machine using the command line.

I need to open them on the settings/cookies page.

I can open any web page like this:

`open -a "Google Chrome" http://stackoverflow.com`

But

`open -a "Google Chrome" chrome://settings`

gives me an error:

`The file /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/chrome:/settings does not exist.`

How to overcome?

Answers suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/558672/open-chrome-and-launch-the-settings-page) don't suit

Comment: have you tried quoting the url?

Comment: yes, sure. I did it

Comment: how about `about:settings` ?

Comment: The same, it does not work