# How to open chrome:// pages from Linux Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome, linux-terminal

**No problem** in opening URLs from command line:

```
google-chrome --new-window 'https://www.google.com/'
```

But these ones, (as of May 2023) **don't work:**

```
google-chrome --new-window 'chrome://settings'
google-chrome --new-window 'chrome://extensions'
google-chrome --new-window 'chrome://flags'
... etc
```

Any workaround to have these pages opened from the command line?

Comment: Looks impossible to achieve this way. Chrome validates the protocol and nothing except `http(s)://` and `file://` works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open chrome and launch the settings page](https://superuser.com/questions/558672/open-chrome-and-launch-the-settings-page)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that only `http` and `file` schema works. Your link is helpful. Since I'm using Linux and not Windows, AHK doesn't work. I made it work with `xdotool` instead. The workaround is similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct answer:** Won't work (so far).

**Workaround:** Used `xdotool` for X11 on Linux.

Example code for `xdotool`:

```
google-chrome --new-window && xdotool type 'chrome://extensions'
xdotool key Return
```